# Vim fugitive back from :Glog

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I'm look for vim command which will exit from Glog'ed file view back to the normal (original) file.

EXAMPLE:

Let say I'm viewing a file with vim.

After entering `:Glog` I'm able to browse through all git versions of this file.

I'm looking for command (or something) which let's me go back to viewing current file version so I can modify and save this file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting [the README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/bdd216827ae53cdf70d933bb30762da9bf42cad4/README.markdown):

> When you're done, use `:Gedit` in the historic buffer to go back to the work tree version.

(It's mentioned in relation to `:Gblame`, but `:Gedit` works with `:Glog` too—I checked.)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the hint.